# is there anyway tool or add-on to support capabilities like Endeca experience manager in ElasticSearch/Solr search?

Tags: solr, elasticsearch, endeca, experience-manager

I am looking for an alternate solution for endeca. Obvious alternates (though not 100%) replacement of Endeca, i find Solr & ElasticSearch satisfies my key requirements. However i am having challenges in finding a replacement for experience manager where a non-technical user can go and apply a few rules. I have seen Front-end list from Elasticsearch but none of them will work index meta data. I couldnt find one for Solr.

Any thoughts on this please?

Ravi

Comment: Can you talk more on this experience manager

Comment: experience managaer (with combination of workbench) will let business user to configure dimensions and apply rules on top of them. Business can  execute query and analyse the data using meta-information (from dimensions) provided by endeca core platform.